# Kotlin - how to find number of repeated values in a list?

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I have a list, e.g like:

```
val list = listOf("orange", "apple", "apple", "banana", "water", "bread", "banana")
```

How can i check how many times apple is duplicated in this list?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
list.count { it == "apple" }
```

Documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/count.html

Answer (score 189):

One way to find all the repeated values in a list is using [groupingBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) and then filter the values which are `> 1`. E.g.

```
val list = listOf("orange", "apple", "apple", "banana", "water", "bread", "banana")
println(list.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().filter { it.value > 1 })
```

Output

```
{apple=2, banana=2}
```

Comment: If you don't care of knowing which index has an overlapping value (e.g. for validation), `println(list.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().any { it.value > 1 })` would be more efficient since it stops on the first occurrence.

Comment: I added this extension function on my projects for find repeated items in Iterable by a Predicate: inline fun <T, K> Iterable<T>.findRepeatedItemsBy(crossinline keySelector: (T) -> K):Map<K, Int> =
    groupingBy(keySelector)
        .eachCount()
        .filter { it.value > 1 }

Comment: Is there a simple way to count items in `Flow` like this?