# Kotlin finding duplicate items in mutableList

Tags: list, kotlin, model, data-class, mutablelist

I have a List

```
 val shoeCart = ShoeRepository.getShoeFromCart(this@ActivityCart)
```

from ShoeRepository

```
 fun getShoeFromCart(context: Context): List<ShoeModel> {
    return getCart(context)
}
```

ShoeModel is a data class

```
data class ShoeModel
```

I want to find out if my shoeCart has duplicate entries in it, and if it does, how many?

Comment: How you are going to find duplicate, based on model name?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/47200815/6962183 ?

Comment: i saw that posting but couldn't figure out how to apply it to a more complex data type (ShoeModel in my case)

Comment: If you're just using the inherent equality of the data class, it's simpler. Use `groupBy { it }`. If you don't care *which* items are duplicates, the easiest would probably be `val numDuplicates = list.size - list.distinct().size`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data classes have their `equals` method implemented, so we can use `eachCount` Map extension to map values to their quantities.

```kotlin
data class ShoeModel(val someProperty: Int)

fun main() {
    val source = listOf(ShoeModel(1), ShoeModel(2), ShoeModel(1), ShoeModel(2), ShoeModel(3))
    println(source.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().filter { (_, v) -> v >= 2 })
}
```

The output of this snippet is `{ShoeModel(someProperty=1)=2, ShoeModel(someProperty=2)=2}`.